# CSS, color, parameters, same

Tags: css

Sorry, I lost few years in IT ) 
So, here is my question:
I have a long ".css" file and a lot of structures like

```
color: #567567;
```

in it. So, Is here a metрod to use some construction like

```
color: $mycolor
```

or not?

PS: sorry for my English.. I drank a few years )))))))

Comment: try sass or less..http://sass-lang.com/ ,
http://lesscss.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not (yet) possible across all browsers in pure CSS, it's currently just an [experimental technology](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables#Browser_compatibility) (also see this [compatibility table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables)).

A way to achieve that is using tools like [less](http://lesscss.org/) or [sass](http://sass-lang.com/) that support variables and then compile their files into pure CSS.

An example taken from the less website:

```
@base: #f938ab;

.box-shadow(@style, @c) when (iscolor(@c)) {
  -webkit-box-shadow: @style @c;
  box-shadow:         @style @c;
}
.box-shadow(@style, @alpha: 50%) when (isnumber(@alpha)) {
  .box-shadow(@style, rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha));
}
.box {
  color: saturate(@base, 5%);
  border-color: lighten(@base, 30%);
  div { .box-shadow(0 0 5px, 30%) }
}
```

compiles to:

```
.box {
  color: #fe33ac;
  border-color: #fdcdea;
}
.box div {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Comment: may be, I was not correct.. I want to have some way to change a color in all .css by one moving...